# "Popular question" badge received without having a question with 1,000 views

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho

The other day I got the `Popular question` badge, but as you can see I don't have any question with 1,000 views.

Comment: @Bozho: I couldn't pick an accurate close reason, so I went with what I thought was closest.  I see you picked "noise or pointless" which would have just seemed rude coming from someone else. :)

Comment: @Bill How is this too localized? This mistake could happen to anyone who gets the popular badge, and is not looking for the "1k" marker. Granted, it's not that likely, but it IS StackExchange related, and it IS applicable to other users who get the badge.

Comment: @devinb: @Bozho asked for this to be closed (via moderator flag).  I picked what I thought was the closest reason.  I agree that it doesn't quite fit in the "too localized" category, but there's not really a good fit.  Do you think it should just stay open?  @Bozho, would you have any objections to keeping this question around?

Comment: @Bill I TOTALLY missed that the vote to close came from him. I apologize.

Comment: @devinb: No worries.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - no problem, let it stay :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one here :)

[Eclipse autocomplete (content assist) with facelets (jsf) and xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml)

Comment: damn.. sorry.. I don't know why I expected 1,000 rather than 1k. And I expected other questions to have gained more :)

Comment: Ah yeah, it happens sometimes, and I think I saw some similar reports like yours :-)